# Must I configure persistence and unload settings explicitly when using SqlInstanceStore?

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4

I have a self-hosted WF 4 service that's making use of the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore. I'm configuring it like so:

```
        var behavior = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreBehavior(connStr);
        TimeSpan detectionPeriod = behavior.RunnableInstancesDetectionPeriod;
        behavior.InstanceCompletionAction = InstanceCompletionAction.DeleteNothing;
        behavior.InstanceLockedExceptionAction = InstanceLockedExceptionAction.AggressiveRetry;
        behavior.InstanceEncodingOption = InstanceEncodingOption.None;
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
```

Futher on down in my code, I'm explitly adding the IdleBehavior behaviour to the host in order to ensure unloading is being applied. Basically, I'm unsure what the SqlInstanceStore does in terms of, specifically, unloading of workflows. Does it manage this itself, or do I still need to add my IdleBehavior, like so:

```
        // Idle behaviour
        var idleBehavior = new WorkflowIdleBehavior();

        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(idleBehavior);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WorkflowIdleBehavior will let the WorkflowServiceHost automatically persist/unload workflows when they are not active. You don't need to do this but it helps with the scalabilty. Even without the idle behavior the workflow state will be saved during the execution.

Comment: Thanks Maurice. If it is saved during the execution via the InstanceStore's internal management is it safe to assume it is also automatically unloading workflows from memory too?

Comment: No, the state will be saved as a result of some actions but that will not unload the workflow instance from memory. You need to do that explicitly either using the idle behavior, closing the service host or using the control endpoint.